# Null pointer exception when calling JPA named query

Tags: eclipse, jpa, glassfish, persistence

I know there are many questions like this here but I've looked at tons and still haven't been able to solve my problem.

I am trying call a named query. I have the following:

```
@Stateless
public class ClientCFacade extends AbstractFacade<ClientC>  {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "the_database")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public ClientCFacade() {
        super(ClientC.class);
    }

    public List<ClientC> findByClientId(Integer clientId) {
        try {

            List<ClientC> clientCsList = em.createNamedQuery(ClientCs.FIND_BY_CLIENT_ID, ClientC.class).
                    setParameter("clientId", clientId)
                    .getResultList();


            return clientCsList;

        } catch (NoResultException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "clients")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = ClientCs.FIND_BY_CLIENT_ID,
                query = "select cc" +
                        "from " +
                        "ClientCs cc " +
                        "WHERE " +
                        "cc.clientId= :clientId")
})
public class ClientCs implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final String FIND_BY_CLIENT_ID = "ClientCs.findByClientId";

 @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "client_id", nullable = false)
    private Integer clientId;
```

with all the getters and setters.

And I call it like:

```
List<ClientC> Cs = clientCFacade.findByClientId(1234);
```

My error is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at the.package.name.ClientCFacade.findByClientId(ClientCFacade.java:56)
            at the.package.name.service.ApiService.runTransaction(ApiService.java:413)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any help is seriously appreciated.

Comment: How does that even compile? You are passing a String to a method which expects an Integer...

Comment: You are trying to set a parameter named `id`, but the parameter in the NamedQuery is defined as `clientId`. There is also a missing space between `select cc` and `from ` in the NamedQuery.

Comment: I fixed this in my code and ran it again - I get exactly the same error.

Comment: `clientCFacade` seems to be null at `List<ClientC> Cs = clientCFacade.findByClientId(1234);` .You probably has some issue injecting the component.

Comment: I agree. Yet I don't know what the correct means of injecting the component is then. The class that calls the method is part of a REST API. The only annotation in this class are Path and POST and GET.
How do I inject it correctly? I've tried using the EJB annotation and creating a new instance when I initialised it.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting a parameter which doesn't exist in your named query.
Replace id with clientId in the method `public List<ClientC> findByClientId(String clientId)`

It should look like this:

```
 List<ClientC> clientCsList = em.createNamedQuery(ClientCs.FIND_BY_CLIENT_ID, ClientC.class).
                setParameter("clientId", clientId)
                .getResultList();
```

Comment: I made this change and tried it again. I still get the same error though.

Comment: Please upload more stack trace with the thrown exception. And please update your code, because there are still many compilation errors.

Comment: i've uploaded the full stack trace and fixed the parameter name

Comment: The only place where you can get a NullPointerException in the method 'findByClientId' is when em is null. Did you define your persistence unit "the_database"  in the persistence.xml? By the way, there are still some problems. 1. The parameter of the method 'findByClientId' has to be of the type String. 2. The result class of your named query has to be 'ClientCs.class' and not 'ClientC.class'

Comment: I am a newby in javaee (doing this for studies...). In my case em was null. Thanks a.am through your comment I solved it.